# Avoid loading data again when finishing activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

In my main Activity of the app, I download some user data at the `onStart()`. When I open the Settings and I hit the `Back` button, I finish the `Settings Activity` and I return to the main Activity. The problem is that the data is being re-downloaded.

So, how can avoid the re-downloading of data?

I've though about `startActivityForResult` but I don't know how to use it and I do not understand how it works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: post ur code of `back` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a static variable in your main activity class like this:

```
public static bool download = true;
```

When you are returning from settings change its value to false like:

```
MainActivity.download = false;
```

And put your download method inside an if statement like this:

```
if (download) {
yourdownloadcode();
}
```

Comment: I need the code in the `onStart()` so I'll use your idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is the usual behavior of Android. When you launch your "Settings Activity" your "Main Activity: calls onStop and the Activity is stopped. Now when you click the back button  from the "Settings Activity" the "Main Activity" comes to the forefront and the onStart method is called again. Since you say that you are downloading the data in the onStart method, the data will again get downloaded.

You can avoid that by downloading the data in the onCreate Method.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the download in the `onStart()`.

Answer (score 1):

When your main activity become visible after you press `Back` button on your Settings activity, `onStart` method is called once again (see [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)). It is why you start re-downloading data once again. So, keep some flag which indicates, that you already started download task. But keep in mind that your main activity can be killed any time after its `onPause` method get called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load data only ones you can use Activity `onCreate`. Here is the activity lifecicle information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

```
startActivityForResult
```

you can use like a callback for your settings screen - if you need to change Main Activity layout after you change configuration on your Settings screen. You can find an example here http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

Comment: Thank you, but I need the download in the `onStart()`.