# Is there a way to tell whether an activity is starting?

Tags: android, android-activity

Similar to Activity's isFinishing() API for use in onPause(), is there a good mechanism to determine whether the activity is being created when in onResume()?

Comment: Hm... activity is created in the `onCreate()`, and it's started in the `onStart()`. What else mechanisms do you need to determine when the activity is being created and started? ...or maybe I didn't understand correctly the question.

Comment: I want to perform a task, such as populate a list, only when returning to the activity -- not when creating it for the first time.

Comment: Now I got it. Then the solutions described below with the flag, should work fine.

Comment: This seems a similar question. Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842051/avoid-loading-data-again-when-finishing-activity/11842382#11842382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a boolean variable that saves the state of "isStarting".

```
boolean isStarting;
```

In your onCreate method, you'd set it to true:

```
isStarting = true;
```

So in you onResume() method you can check if the activity is starting:

```
    if(isStarting == true) {
    // Activity has been created!
//set the variable to false
isStarting = false;
    }
    else {
    // Nope...
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean value, initially false and you onResume should look something like this:

```
if (!flag)
{
    // Activity is created for the first time
    flag = true;
}
else
{
    // Activity was created before
}
```